# Making a page version with the OneOne API

Tags: java, onenote-api

I've got a java program updating a page in a OneNote notebook.

I'd would like it to make a "version" of this page before modifying it.

Not a mere copy, but a version that OneNote recognize.
Is there anyone knowing how to do this with OneNote Rest Api ?
I couldn't find anything.

[EDIT]

To make it clear on what I call versions, it is these automatic copies taken by OneNote when one modifies a page:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneNote page versions is an already existing feature in OneNote.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-a-list-of-recent-changes-in-a-notebook-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-55dc5183-9112-4c7e-a9cf-44cd66c19c77?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

However, page versions aren't supported in the OneNote API - I encourage you to create a uservoice item for us to track this and link it here.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis

Comment: My Onenote is in french, so difficult for me to point the right english term.
What I aim to get is as follow: when you edit manually through OneNote, OneNote takes a copy of the page, invisible in the GUI unless you ask for "Show the page's versions" in the contextual menu. Then you can see all the copies taken by OneNote + the date of the copy. These are the kind of versions I'd like to make.

Comment: This is an already existing feature in OneNote:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/See-a-list-of-recent-changes-in-a-notebook-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-55dc5183-9112-4c7e-a9cf-44cd66c19c77?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: The question is : how can I do this with the Rest API ?